# Batch rename files that do not match pattern

Tags: bash

I do not have programming experience and mostly use one-liner or sometimes more to get the job done. I am having problem to batch rename the files that do not match a particular pattern.

**Sample file-names from directory:**

```
Meeting_Packages.pdf
13_textfile0
19_textfile0
23_textfile0
29_textfile0
33_textfile1
45_textfile0
5_textfile3
Membership.pdf
13_textfile1
19_textfile1
23_textfile1
29_textfile1
34_textfile0
46_textfile0
6_textfile0
xyz2009.pdf
13_textfile2
19_textfile2
23_textfile2
29_textfile2
34_textfile1
47_textfile0
6_textfile1
meeting.ics
```

I want to rename the files e.g. `Meeting_Packages.pdf`, `Membership.pdf`, `meeting.ics` and `xyz2009.pdf` to the file from where they came (input file). Actually it is output of `ripmime` with mails as `xx_textfilex` and others are attachments. I want to name attachments as the original input file

**My Code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=*.mime
for f in $FILES
do
    echo "Processing $f"
    #rip mails into attachments and text files also add a prefix to text files
    ripmime -i $f -d ~/test/ripmime --prefix 
    #Remove white spaces from files 
    rename 's/ /_/g' ~/test/ripmime/*
    #rename attachments as original input files
    rename 's/\[^0-9]/'$f/ ~/test/ripmime/* 
done
```

My problem is the last rename line where I try to filter files other than `xx_textfilex` and rename. I tried different regular expressions but could not do that. I can select and rename the textfiles by:

```
rename 's/textfiles/'$f/ ~/test/ripmime/*
```

but I need the inverse of that and rename files other then textfiles.

How can I do this?

Comment: maybe mmv can do this. http://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html

Comment: I can see how it can be done, but you need to provide some sample resulting file names. _How_ should the PDF files in your current example be renamed after the command has been run? I find this part to be ambiguous at the moment: if they should be renamed as the input file as you say, that would result in multiple files with the same file name, which is not possible.

Comment: It looks like you are working in a temporary directory anyway; have you considered moving the files you want to keep out of the way, then using something like `rename` to rename the remaining files, then move the first set back to where they were?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `ls` and `grep -v`:

```
ls | grep -v ".*textfile.*" | while read filename; do
  # rename $filename to something
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I use https://gist.github.com/995151

`rename 's/\.bak$//' *.pdf`

Comment: I just don't want to rename *.pdf files as I don't know what formats they could be in. Therefore just want to rename all the files as input file that ARE NOT xx_textfilex. I used rip mime to extract mails and attachments from MIME formatted mails. Do you have some thing in mind for that?